# Can't open the info.plist in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, info.plist

when i try to open info.plist in xcode i got an internal error :

```
[PBXFileReference plistStructureDefinitionIdentifier]: unrecognized select or sent to instance 0x30d0f80
```

I'm running on xcode 3.1 and iphone sdk 3.0  on VMWare 
Application type : Cocoa Touch Application

Comment: we need your code as well as your error.

Comment: it happens with new projects too

Comment: Have you ever 'not' had this error? It may be the VMWare setup

Comment: Actually , it is the first time to run on VMWare .

Answer (score 1):

Try opening with some text editor and check if it is not corrupted or bad formatted.
Can you open another info.plist? Does this happen only with one file?

Comment: I can't open any info.plist files even the new projects which are untouched